# Which is the most expensive broom in current canon?

Tags: harry-potter, flying-brooms

There are many flying brooms in the world of *Harry Potter*, like the Nimbus series, the Cleansweep series, the Firebolt etc.

However, I didn't find any concrete information about which broom is the costliest of all.
I understand that some brooms will be best for some situations or people. But still I want to know which broom is the most expensive.

Comment: Good luck getting an answer to that

Comment: By "now" do you mean as of the end of book 7? I guess it would probably be a Firebolt.

Comment: By "now" means after quidditch through the ages and fantastic beasts and where to find them and.. I think you get the drift.

Comment: If I was to downvote, I'd downvote for apparrent lack of any up-to-date canon information whatsoever.

Comment: @vap78 the question now asks for the most expensive broom. There may not be an answer in cannon, but it is **not** opinion based.

Comment: @SQB an edit that completely changes the question invalidates all comments and votes. It is actually another question.

Comment: Well the firebolt is the best as of now and thats fact no opinion, and it also appears to be the most expensive current broom, whether or. Ot some old collectors broom could fetch more is another question

Comment: @Gallifreian - Two years ago isn't *that* out of date.

Comment: @Himarm - I highly doubt that it is the *Firebolt*, seeing as that model has since been succeeded by the *Firebolt Supreme*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While we do not know the individual prices, the following five brooms were used during the last (2014) Quidditch World Cup, and were probably among the most expensive brooms of the time.

- Varápidos
- Starsweeper XXI
- Yajirushi
- Firebolt Supreme
- Thunderbolt VII

<sub>(Sources: [Japan vs Nigeria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgPkF.png) and [Place Your Bets with Ludo Bagman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdwzW.png))</sub>

It is of course very possible that the market has somewhat chaged over the past two years, but that is the most up-to-date info that J.K. Rowling has provided us.